# Harmonic oscillator with damping attrition

Tags: differential-equations, physics, event-detection

Considering the following physical situation:

[image]

and writing the following code:

```
m := 1.52
g := 9.81
us := 0.15
uk := 0.10
k := 2.12
xi := 4.00
vi := 0.00
tmax := 10

P := m g
Fs := us P
Fk := uk P
Fe[t_] := -k x[t]

sol = NDSolve[{
        Fe[t] - Sign[x'[t]] Fk == m x''[t],
        x[0] == xi,
        x'[0] == vi},
      x, {t, 0, tmax}];

Plot[Evaluate[{
        Sign[x'[t]] Fs, 
        Fe[t], 
        x[t]} /. sol],
    {t, 0, tmax},
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "fct[t]"},
    PlotLegends -> {"-Fs", "Fe", "x"}]
```

you get the following graph:

[image]

which shows that oscillations are over for $t \approx 8\,s$ **causes kinematic friction**.

On the other hand, putting `us = 0.40` you get this other graph:

[image]

which shows that oscillations are over for $t \approx 3\,s$ **causes static friction**.

*Question: is it possible to automate all this by making the `x(t)` graph plot until the motion stops?*

Comment: Ok, there are two situations with different amplitudes of you resulting functions, and what?
Could you clarify, what namely do you want to automate?

Comment: Two questions: You use `Fk` in `NDSolve` but plot `Fs`. Is this intended? Secondly, what exactly happens at 8s resp. 3s? I don't see anything significant at those times in the plots you provided. (Also, `x[t]` seems nearly identical between the two plots, is this intended?)

Comment: Maybe you added the wrong image, because even in your second graph the motion continues till 8 s.

Comment: I see, so the plot of $x(t)$ in the second graph is *wrong* because it should stop there at ${\sim}3\ \mathrm s$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html):

```
sol = NDSolve[
  {
    Fe[t] - Sign[x'[t]] Fk == m x''[t],
    x[0] == xi,
    x'[0] == vi,
    WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0 && Fs > Abs[k x[t]], tmax = t; "StopIntegration"]
  }
  , x, {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

Note that this automatically sets `tmax`, so you don't need to specify anything before. The only thing to note is that you can't replace `k x[t]` with `Fe[t]`, since `WithEvent` doesn't see the `x[t]` in that case. You could write (note the `Evaluate` wrapped around the condition)

```
WhenEvent[Evaluate[x'[t] == 0 && Fs > Abs[Fe[t]]], tmax = t; "StopIntegration"]
```

if you really want to write `Fe[t]`.

For `us=0.15`:

[image: Solution for us=0.15]

For `us=0.4`:

[image: Solution for is=0.4]

Comment: Glad it works for you. Please don't forget to mark your question as answered.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but something like `WhenEvent[If[us != 0, x'[t] == 0 && Fs > Abs[k x[t]], t >= 10], tmax = t; "StopIntegration"]` should do the trick