# Numerical integration of NDSolve solution

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics

Linking to what is discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153720/harmonic-oscillator-with-damping-attrition), writing the following code:

```
m := 1.52
g := 9.81
us := 0.30
uk := 0.20
k := 10.12
F := 1.00
xi := 2.20
vi := 0.00

sol = NDSolve[{

    F - k x[t] - Sign[x'[t]] uk m g == m x''[t],
    x[0] == xi,
    x'[0] == vi,

    WhenEvent[
     x'[t] == 0 && us m g >= Abs[F - k x[t]],
     tmax = t; "StopIntegration"]

    }, x, {t, 0, 10^4}];
```

and  recalling the **theorem of work and kinetic energy**: *the work done by all the forces acting on a body is equal to the variation of its kinetic energy*, that is $\sum_j W_j = K_f - K_i$, I calculated:

```
NIntegrate[Sign[x'[t]] F - k x[t] - uk m g /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, tmax}] // Chop
```

> -19.3941

```
1/2 m x'[tmax]^2 - 1/2 m x'[0]^2 /. sol[[1]] // Chop
```

> 0

I don't understand why work is not zero as the kinetic energy variation! Ideas?

---

Writing:

```
NIntegrate[m x''[t] x'[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, tmax}] // Chop
```

you have perfect match!

Comment: "the work done by all the forces acting on a body is equal to the variation of its kinetic energy":`NIntegrate[Sign[x'[t]] F - k x[t] - uk m g /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, tmax}] // Chop ` does not calculate the work but Intergates the force over time (work is force integrated over distance).

Comment: This is a one dimensional problem; the force is constrained to point along or against the direction of x.  I suspect you'll have more luck with:  $W=\int\, dx\, F = \int \,dt\, x' F$.  I recommend warming up by using the same code on simple harmonic oscillator, then Damped SHO, then Driven Damped SHO, etc.  Debugging where you have complete analytic control.